# SendMessage fails to send custom message to main window

Tags: c++, winapi

Before beginning to read the problem please note i read Petzold's book (windows programming 5th edition)!

In form.h i have declared the custom message named CMessage (it stand for "custom message", which later calls the method for creating a button), in formbutton.cpp i am sending message from its constructor to the main window which is created in form.cpp. I found out from getLastError method in my helper class that send message fails because of invalid window handle, it is strange because if i use isWindow(forms.mainWindowHandle) before sending the message i got messagebox that shows "operation completed successfully". The same design worked before splitting whole code into multiple headers and cpps, now its broken.

```
******
step by step debugging :

        form myform(hInstance);
        form::form(HINSTANCE hInstanceForm);
         HWND form::Createform(HWND handle, HINSTANCE hInstance, int xPos , int yPos , int xSize , int ySize);
    Formbutton::Formbutton(BOOL create);
    form::form();
    SendMessage(forms.mainWindowHandle, CMessage,0 ,0);//error
    //rest of the code and main window is shown but not the button
******
```

formbutton.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "FormButton.h"
#include "Form.h"
#include "helper.h"
Formbutton::Formbutton(){}
Formbutton::Formbutton(BOOL create)
{
    helper help;
    form forms;
    if (create)
    {
        SendMessage(forms.mainWindowHandle, CMessage,0 ,0); //same with PostMessage
        help.getLastError();
    }
}

HWND Formbutton::createButton(HWND button, HWND parent)
{
    button = CreateWindow(TEXT("Button"), // window class name
        TEXT("Button"), // window caption
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP, // window style
        500, // initial x position
        500, // initial y position
        300, // initial x size
        500, // initial y size
        parent, // parent window handle
        NULL, // window menu handle
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(parent, -6), // program instance handle
        NULL); // creation parameters
    ShowWindow(button, SW_SHOW);
    return button;
}
```

form.h

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#define CMessage (WM_USER+0x0001)
class form 
{
private:
    HWND Createform(HWND handle, HINSTANCE hInstance, int xPos = CW_USEDEFAULT, int yPos = CW_USEDEFAULT, int xSize = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN), int ySize = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN));
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
protected:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
public:
     HWND mainWindowHandle; 
    form::form();
    form::form(HINSTANCE hInstanceForm);
    form::~form();

    WPARAM updateForm();
};
```

form.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "Form.h"
#include "FormButton.h"

 LRESULT CALLBACK form::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;
     Formbutton fb;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        return 0;
    case WM_PAINT:
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rect, TRUE);
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(SYSTEM_FIXED_FONT));
        SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case CMessage: //this is the custom message
        fb.createButton(fb.buttonHandle, hwnd);

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

 HWND form::Createform(HWND handle, HINSTANCE hInstance, int xPos , int yPos , int xSize , int ySize)
{
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = TEXT("Framework");
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"),
            TEXT("Framework"), MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    handle = CreateWindow(TEXT("Framework"), // window class name
        TEXT("The Hello Program"), // window caption
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SIZEBOX | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL, // window style
        xPos, // initial x position
        yPos, // initial y position
        xSize, // initial x size
        ySize, // initial y size
        NULL, // parent window handle
        NULL, // window menu handle
        hInstance, // program instance handle
        NULL); // creation parameters
    //ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
    UpdateWindow(handle);
    return handle;
}
WPARAM form::updateForm()
{
    ShowWindow(mainWindowHandle, 10);
    UpdateWindow(mainWindowHandle);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
form::form()
{
}
form::form(HINSTANCE hInstanceForm)
{
    mainWindowHandle = Createform(mainWindowHandle, hInstanceForm);
}

form::~form()
{

}
```

helper.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "helper.h"
#include <strsafe.h>
void helper::getLastError()
{
    wchar_t buf[256];
    FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(),
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buf, 256, NULL);
    MessageBox(NULL, buf, TEXT("error"), MB_OK);
}
```

source.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Form.h"
#include "FormButton.h"
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
        form myform(hInstance);
        Formbutton btn(true);
        myform.updateForm();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating two instances of `form`: one in your `WinMain()` and one in your `Formbutton` constructor. You want to add your button to the former, but you are really adding it to the latter, and the latter ceases to exist once the constructor returns.

I'm not sure how you want to structure your program, but my suggestion is to pass the correct parent form as a `form *` parameter to the `Formbutton` constructor.

Comment: i moved sendmessage() to my source.cpp and it is working, thanks for answer !

Comment: Sorry for late reply but using the wrong object was the problem, now it is solved by passing proper 'form' object. Thanks!